# How to add multiple buttons to a row dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, row

Does anybody know how to add multiple buttons to a table row dynamically in Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this and see if it's what your are looking for.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity class:

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.main );
        Button b = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button1 );
        b.setOnClickListener( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById( R.id.tableLayout1 );

        int buttonsInRow = 0;
        int numRows = table.getChildCount();
        TableRow row = null;
        if( numRows > 0 ){
            row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt( numRows - 1 );
            buttonsInRow = row.getChildCount();         
        }

        if( numRows == 0 || buttonsInRow == 3 ){
            row = new TableRow( this );
            table.addView( row );
            buttonsInRow = 0;
        }
        if( buttonsInRow < 3 ){
            Button b = new Button( this );
            row.addView( b, 100, 50 );
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!!!!! You might not have guessed it, but I a relative newby to android and had no idea how to use .getChildAt() or .getChildCount(). But now I do and things are looking so much better!

Comment: I had a similiar problem, adding a button to a tablerow of 1 button or creating a new tablerow if there were already 2 buttons. This code was perfect.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Also, if you want to automate the button generation, just put it in a for loop. Just set the limit to how many buttons you want added.

Answer (score 1):

Here layout is a TableLayout.If you want to add a row dynamically and buttons in that row can use the follwoing code

```
TableRow tr1=new TableRow(this);
                    Button tv=new Button(this);
                tv.setText("");
                tr1.addView(tv,250,30);
                Button tv1=new Button(this);
                tv1.setText("");
                tr1.addView(tv1,100,30);
                layout.addView(tr1);
```

If you already have row in the layout then just fetch the row and add buttons to the row

Comment: Many thanks but I should have been more specific. I want to click on a button that will add up to 3 buttons per row. After the first row is full, a new row will be created and a new button will be added to it.

Comment: ok this code shows how to add a row and Button dynamically.change it as you need

Answer (score 0):

After searching for 30 sec I found http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically - this should help you, just change TextViews to Buttons.