# Create a specific number of buttons

Tags: java, android, class, button, layout

I want to create a layout in Android in a java class. I need that the user introduce a number between 1 to 20 and this create the number of butttons that the user has chosen.

I know that this is possible in Java but I don't know if this is possible in Android, any idea?Thnaks!!

Comment: Merlevede Can you explain me how to do it or have you got any examples of this?? thank you in advance!!

Comment: If you do this programmatically, you can easily loop through from 0 - n and add them to the layout.

Comment: Show me the code you have so far, so I can guide you further.

Comment: I'm going to explain my situation a bit more. I have a layout in XML created, anf I want to modified it when I clicked a play button. Then I would that this layout changed to other doing what in the first question I tell.

Comment: I wan tto put these specific buttons in a determined area of the layout

Comment: I post the code here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994278/dynamic-buttons-android-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout buttonsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttons_layout);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfButtons;i++){
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Buttin "+(i+1));
        button.set....other attributes
        buttonsLayout.addView(button, layoutParams);
    }
```

Comment: also look at this question  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868957/how-to-add-multiple-buttons-to-a-row-dynamically-in-android)