# changed position buttons in dynamic layout

Tags: button, dynamic

I have this XML.I want to include dynamic buttons in the linearlayoutUp of the XML code with the Java code, and I want that this buttons appear in horizontal position, any idea to hanged vertical to horizontal

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutUp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scrollbars="vertical" >

         </ScrollView> 

</LinearLayout>

<com.example.nuevo.ControladorView
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.83" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayoutDown"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with the second `LinearLayout` and `ScrollView`?

Comment: that linear is the area to create the buttons. the number of buttons could be high so I introduce the scrollView inside the layout4

Comment: hey! I delete the scroll ant it works,but i want to include the scroll, how I can do it? thanks thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a `ScrollView`, you put it around the Layout. Also, you should use a [`HorizontalScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) since your list is horizontal.

Try this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
  android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayoutUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I would like to do two buttons one up and one down and the functionality for all the same, wiht a tableLayout instead linear??

Comment: I have a XML file with a canvas and two linear layout, one up of the canvas and the other at the bottom. I want to have four buttons at the top and the other at the bottom, when I clicked one, (play button) I would like that this linear changed the buttons

thanks